# Float a child div over it's parent

Tags: html, css

I have a div with fixed width.
Inside that, there is a table. (Table may contain any number of columns)

On hover of each  it shows a popup div.

But the popups for the tds of last column hide, because of the fixed width of the table containing div.

How to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: You might want to try adding some code of what you have tried…

Comment: please add code or image

Comment: Hi.... I've added a pic. And the code is coming from some server side templating. So I don't have to to provide

Comment: view source of the page from your browser and you will get plain html

Comment: That's very hazy @GCyrillus .... Everything is jumbled there

Comment: @prasenjitPaul :try adding `overflow:visible;` to your fixed width div.